# android saving and loading PNG bitmaps differences

Tags: android, bitmap, compression, png, save

I'm trying to solve my problem for a several days now and I couldn't figure it out.
My application uses a Bitmap to process image's pixels in a similar way steganography does.
After I modify Bitmap and get lets say ModifiedBitmap and check the pixel values everything is correct.
Problems begins after I save the Bitmap as PNG with compress method. When I load ModifiedBitmap back to memory pixel values are changed. As I store the Bitmap in a PNG format with ARGB_8888 I assumed that the values will be the same after saving and loading the image in PNG format.

For more detail I'm loading the bitmap with the following code:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opt.inDither = false;
opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, opt)
```

Whatever the Bitmap format is I process it to get the right Bitmap format for my purposes. My aim is to get Bitmap that has alpha and is in the ARGB_8888 config. I prepare new Bitmap with the following:

```
int width = this.imageToProcess.getWidth();
int height = this.imageToProcess.getHeight();

Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        int pixel = this.imageToProcess.getPixel(i, j);
            int newColor = 0;
            if (this.imageToProcess.hasAlpha()) {
                newColor = Color.argb(Color.alpha(pixel), Color.red(pixel), Color.green(pixel), Color.blue(pixel));
            } else {
                newColor = Color.argb(255, Color.red(pixel), Color.green(pixel), Color.blue(pixel));
            }
        dest.setPixel(i, j, newColor);
        }
}
```

When I use such a prepare method I always get the right format of the Bitmap with the right parameters and configuration. So now, the Bitmap has config ARGB_8888 and has the alpha values. Lets say I've got the PreparedBitmap. I also checked the Bitmap properties and it is exactly ARGB_8888 and hasAlpha is true. So far now, it is all as it should be.
Then I make some sort of pixel modifing on the PreparedBitmap and it is ready to be saved.
I use the following code for saving the Bitmap as a PNG:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
OutputStream fOut = null;
File file = new File(path, "image.png");
fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
modifiedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
fOut.flush();
fOut.close();
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getName(),file.getName());
```

After that I have stored PNG image file.
Then I want to load ModifiedBitmap again and process the Bitmap in inverse manner. My prerequisitie is that the ModifiedBitmap has exactly same pixel values as I modified it in the first step. I load the Bitmap through the same procedure:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opt.inDither = false;
opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, opt)
```

But he loaded ModifiedBitmap when it was saved before has different pixel values. Also it hasn't alpha values (hasAlpha is false) but the config is the same ARGB_8888.
Does anybody know why is that? It is ARGB_8888 Bitmap so there shouldn't be a differences in pixel values. Does android compress PNG Bitmap somehow? How should I save the PNG images to prevent from pixel values changes?

If the ModifiedBitmap pixel values is in ARGB_8888 (128, 128, 128, 128) and I save it through Bitmap.compress method I want to get the same values with alpha after loading it again. I'm out of all ideas how to do that.

Comment: Could it be because of premultiplication of alpha during save or reload?